# Controlling state

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, onmousemove

```js
getMouseXY = function(e) {
  tempX = e.pageX
  tempY = e.pageY 

  if (tempX < 0){tempX = 0}
  if (tempY < 0){tempY = 0}  

  document.getElementById("circle1").style.top = (tempY - 25) + "px";
  document.getElementById("circle1").style.left = (tempX - 25) + "px";
  return true
}

document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;

trackCircle = function() {
  document.getElementById("circle1").style.top = "10px";
  document.getElementById("circle1").style.left = "10px";
}

document.getElementById("circle1").addEventListener("click", trackCircle);
```

```html
<div id="circle1" style="width:50px;height:50px;background-color:orange;border-radius:50px;position:absolute;"></div>
```

The idea is the circle tracks your mouse wherever it goes, until you click, then it goes back to its resting spot. The problem is, when I move the mouse again it undoes the resting position, and returns to tracking the document.onmousemove The plan is for it to only resume tracking, once in rest, after you re-hover "circle1" ... and then resumes tracking with document.onmousemove

I know I could call something like this instead of document.onmousemove:

```
document.getElementById("circle1").addEventListener('mousemove', getMouseXY);
```

But the "is the mouse hovering over this specific element?" event is to imprecise and you end up losing your tracking a lot when you move the mouse around quickly.

Seems like I need to build some kind of state machine where its either trackingON or trackingOFF. Where trackingOFF is triggered by clicking the circle and trackingON is triggered by hovering the circle (but then the actual tracking uses document.onmousemove

Comment: I'm confused, like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/ub9v9p0j/5/

Comment: Or like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/ub9v9p0j/6/ ?

Comment: Yes! Almost, but using click on circle to turn off moving, and hover on circle to turn back on

Comment: So like the last one ?

Comment: The first one is almost it, the second one you lose the tracking if you move the mouse fast, which is the prob I was having with using a mouse move event listener on an element.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/15gkb3am/

Comment: Or like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ub9v9p0j/7/**

Answer (score 0):

You need a flag to specify that "I have clicked, stop tracking my mouse" to be set when you click and a check to say "I have moved my mouse over the circle, resume tracking me"

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ub9v9p0j/8/

and the actual code:

```
var stopTracking = false;

getMouseXY = function(e) {
  tempX = e.pageX
  tempY = e.pageY 
  var circle = document.querySelector('#circle1');
  var r = circle.offsetWidth / 2;

  if (tempX < 0){tempX = 0}
  if (tempY < 0){tempY = 0}  

  if (stopTracking) {
    if (Math.pow(tempX - circle.offsetLeft - r, 2) + Math.pow(tempY - circle.offsetTop - r, 2) < r * r) {
      stopTracking = false;
    } else {
        return;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("circle1").style.top = (tempY - 25) + "px";
  document.getElementById("circle1").style.left = (tempX - 25) + "px";
  return true
}

document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;

trackCircle = function() {
  document.getElementById("circle1").style.top = "10px";
  document.getElementById("circle1").style.left = "10px";
  stopTracking = true;
}

document.getElementById("circle1").addEventListener("click", trackCircle);
```